# How can I improve my color change programm?

Tags: python, time, pygame

A few days ago I found a couple of dead pixels on my laptop screen. Googled how to remove them without going to the service center, but nothing helped. I decided to create a simple code myself to go through all possible colors in order to finally make a verdict on whether I should go to a service center or not.

I decided to write code in Python, because on I can quickly create an algorithm that would solve my problem, but I met with a problem in speed.

Walking through one color (blue in my case) takes about 1.64 seconds, then it takes about 29 hours to walk through all the colors, which is quite a long time. Is there any way to speed up the process? Or should I choose some other method?

```py
import pygame

WIDTH = 200
HEIGHT = 200
FPS = 144

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True

r = 0
g = 0
b = 0

while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    b += 1

    if b % 256 == 0:
        b = 0
        g += 1

        if g % 256 == 0:
            g = 0
            r += 1

            if r % 256 == 0:
                break

    screen.fill((r, g, b))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: 256³ divided by frame rate equals thirty-two hours. This will also be a gradual transition and I understand transitions are preferred, so you might just want to flash from black to white in alternate frames. Or get a [utility](http://udpix.free.fr/) designed for this purpose.

Comment: @Rabbid76, when I googled for solutions to the problem, one of the methods said that you can fix a dead pixel by exposing it to different colors. For example, jscreenfix.com service

However, after trying several similar services, I could not solve this problem. So I wanted to create my own code, which will display all possible RGB colors, in the hope that the problem will be solved

Comment: @Rabbid76 If he's trying to physically display each color on the monitor, it makes sense to limit the FPS to his monitor's refresh rate so that each frame actually appears.

Comment: @Rabbid76, Well, this seriously speeds up the process, so much so that everything can be completed in minutes. However, don't I run the risk of missing some frames? My screen is 144hz

The goal is not only for my laptop to go through all the colors, but also for the screen to be able to display all these colors.

Comment: @ClayMix So what is the question? You want to display all the different colors on the screen for a certain time. How would you make it faster? Either make the time interval shorter or display fewer colors.

Comment: [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/38231/what-is-the-best-way-to-fix-a-stuck-pixel-on-an-lcd-screen) has several answers that might help you refine your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your script modified to randomly cycle through RGB on/off permutations:

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 200
HEIGHT = 200
FPS = 144
# permutations of on/off for R, G & B
colours = ((0, 0, 0),
           (255, 0, 0),
           (0, 255, 0),
           (0, 0, 255),
           (255, 255, 0),
           (0, 255, 255),
           (255, 0, 255),
           (255, 255, 255))

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    # testing out the walrus operator
    while (colour := random.choice(colours)) == screen.get_at((0, 0))[:3]:
        # print(f"dupe: {colour} {screen.get_at((0,0))}")
        pass
    # colour = random.choice(colours))  # no dupe check
    screen.fill(colour)
    # print(colour)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

The duplicate colour prevention is a little ugly but I was testing out an [assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions).

Enable the print statements to confirm that you're not getting duplicate colours although it probably doesn't matter. You can get rid of the duplicate check and uncomment the original colour assignment if you don't like the `:=`.